# Does Ionic app development is efficient? Are there any android apps developed in Ionic Framework ?

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to know whether android apps developed in Ionic framework will be efficient are not... Also want to see how these apps work. Is that same as in Native Android Development?

Even I've developed a sample app in Ionic.
Installed on my device.
But after going into next page in app, when I'm pressing the back button on my device it is not going to the previous page, instead it simply exits the application.

Does all Ionic Apps behave in this way? Or Is there anything to do inside my Code?

Answer (score 1):

1).off-course ionic app is different then native.

2). Yes all app close when we click back button form the home page.

when clicking on the back button present in your app it should go to next page. Ionic have some [Default header](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionHeaderBar/) or you can creat your own header you can see it in [css components](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/) available in ionic website.

For handling the page navigation you can use **ng-router** or **ui-router** or **urlrouterprovider** like this in angularjs.

3)**Mobile device back button**

for mobile back button you can override the mobile device back button check out this http://www.gajotres.net/ionic-framework-handling-android-back-button-like-a-pro/ it is an example blog for overriding the back button you can play as you like with mobile device back button.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this application. This is completely designed in IONIC framework.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.savememories

Answer (score 1):

If you are using v2 of the Ionic framework you should be able to use the back button to navigate to the previous page no problem.  Give it a try.

1. Make sure you have latest version of ionic `npm install -g ionic`
2. Create app: `ionic start testApp --v2`
3. run app: `ionic run android`

The back button should work as described